# How to customize a backend running job completion message?

Tags: shell, background-process

Here is the situation, I am running a command (my own executives), in bash shell (Ubuntu), say something like this:

```
[newbie@office currentCaseAFolder]$ FEMSolver &
```

So that the `FEMSolver` job is now running in backend, and let's say it needs around five to ten minutes. But I have more than one cases. so

```
[newbie@office currentCaseAFolder]$ cd ../currentCaseBFolder
[newbie@office currentCaseBFolder]$ FEMSolver &
[newbie@office currentCaseBFolder]$ cd ../currentCaseCFolder
[newbie@office currentCaseCFolder]$ FEMSolver &
[newbie@office currentCaseCFolder]$ cd ../currentCaseDFolder
[newbie@office currentCaseDFolder]$ FEMSolver &
[newbie@office currentCaseDFolder]$ cd ../../postprocessingFolder
```

After a coffee time, I come back, and hit return key, some simulations have finished. so it will show me

```
[2]  + Done           FEMSolver &
[4]  + Done           FEMSolver &
[newbie@office postprocessingFolder]$
```

But this does not give me the clear information from which folder the job was sent!! I hope it could somewhere and somehow be customized to have this effect:

```
[2]  + Done           FEMSolver &  (from folder currentCaseBFolder)
[2]  + Done           FEMSolver &  (from folder currentCaseDFolder)
[newbie@office postprocessingFolder]$
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the `cd` and the `FEMSolver` into a backgrounded subshell, like so:

```
(cd currentCaseAFolder; FEMSolver) &
```

When they finish running you will messages something like the ones below.

```
[2]+  Done                    ( cd currentCaseBFolder; FEMSolver)
[4]+  Done                    ( cd currentCaseDFolder; FEMSolver)
```